# N ' Ary Trees Data Structures

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I was looking at plenty of tree data structures and it is really confusing. Like I understand the basic Binary Trees(also its numerous implementations like the BST Red black trees etc)
But what i really need is some information on N'ary trees.
I need to study various types of N' ary trees and also their performance comparisons.
The only N' ary tree I have seen till now is B+ tree. I need to know which is the fastest N' Ary tree. i.e the most optimized time complexity wise, space complexity is no issue.

Comment: Being a tree with a given amount of children (>1) per node doesn't mean much by itself. There really is very little you can tell about a tree just from that. Time complexity mostly depends on the algorithm you run on it, and the invariants imposed on the tree which can then be exploited by the algorithms. That's true for self-balancing trees, B+ trees, and all other trees. Please clarify your question, as it stands it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, making something a *[K-ary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree) tree*, [image: $k > 2$], does not give any asymptotic advantage over a *binary tree* ([image: $k=2$]). For example, searching a a balanced *binary tree* can be done in [image: $\mathcal O \left(log_2 \ n\right)$] time. Searching a balanced *k-ary tree*, will give you [image: $\mathcal O \left(k\cdot log_k \ n\right)$]. Assuming [image: $k$] is a constant, [image: $log_k n$] and [image: $log n$] for any other base, are equivalent asymptotically (the growth *rates* will be the same for large [image: $n$]). That is, [image: $\mathcal O \left(log_i \ n\right)$] is equivalent to [image: $\mathcal O \left(log_j \ n\right)$] for any [image: $i$] and [image: $j$]. Therefore, [image: $\mathcal O \left(k\cdot log_k \ n\right) =\ $\mathcal O \left(log \ n\right)$].

Practically, however, a *k-ary tree* might result in better memory access patterns, because each node contains [image: $k$] nodes next to eachother, which means the height of the tree is shorter (wikipedia gives the height, [image: $h$], for a complete *k-ary tree* as [image: $h=\left\lceil\log_k (k - 1) + \log_k (n) - 1\right\rceil$], which is asymptotically the same for any constant [image: $k$]), and traversal might jump around less as well, since leaf nodes can contain multiple in-order keys.